# Loading MAMP (Localhost) Data into EditText Issue Android

Tags: java, php, android, android-edittext, localhost

I've got a MAMP (localhost) database and have a profile loaded. I want to be able to load all my profile data so like 9 fields in my multi-line edit text.

There are no errors just my Log it shows success when it retrieves the data but it only displays one of the fields from the database and not all...Any idea how to get all? My php and everything else is fine as I've tested it.

I was wondering if you could help me?

My Class:

```
  String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_get_single_profile = "http://MYIP:8888/android_connect/get_all_profiles.php";


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_USERPROFILE = "UserProfile";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
    private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "lastname";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_COMMENTS = "comments";
    private static final String TAG_AGE = "age";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_HEIGHT = "height";
    private static final String TAG_WEIGHT = "weight";
    private static final String TAG_INFORMATION = "information";


    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_sms);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);



        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProfileDetails().execute();

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString() + displayLocation();
                displayLocation();

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    private String displayLocation(){
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, new LocationListener(){
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {}
            });
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
           return "https://www.google.co.id/maps/@"+latitude+","+longitude;
    }





    //---sends a SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, Home.class), 0);
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);


        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager smms = android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.getDefault();
        smms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProfileDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SendSMS.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Profile details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String...param) {
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_get_single_profile, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_USERPROFILE); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    // instead return your product to onPostExecute
                    return product;
                } else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject product) {
            if (product != null) {
                // product with this pid found
                // Edit Text
                txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);


                // display profile data in EditText
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_COMMENTS));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_AGE));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_GENDER));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_HEIGHT));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_WEIGHT));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_INFORMATION));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-writing the `EditText` field with each item.
To fix it, just create a `StringBuilder` and concatenate each item that is available.
Then, call `txtMessage.setText` at the bottom once you've extracted all of the data.

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject product) {
    if (product != null) {
        // product with this pid found
        // Edit Text
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        StringBuilder jsonStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); //Create StringBuilder for concatenation of JSON results

        // display profile data in EditText
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME));  //Don't set the text here
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME)); //Concatenate each separate item
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_COMMENTS));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_COMMENTS));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_AGE));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_AGE));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_GENDER));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_GENDER));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_HEIGHT));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_HEIGHT));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_WEIGHT));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_WEIGHT));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //txtMessage.setText(product.getString(TAG_INFORMATION));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(product.getString(TAG_INFORMATION));
            jsonStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txtMessage.setText(jsonStringBuilder.toString());
    }

}
```